# Fetching the current Firebase cloud messaging registration token error

Tags: swift, firebase-cloud-messaging, token, firebase-notifications

I'm working on my ios app written in Swift and implementing push notifications using Firebase. I want to send a notification to one device and for that, as far as i understood, I need to find out a FCM registration token of that device first. I'm trying an approach from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/first-message?authuser=2#access_the_registration_token). In particular, it is said that in order to get the token I need to use instanceIDWithHandler: method. For that I added two things:

```
Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
```

and

```
InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
  if let error = error {
    print("Error fetching remote instange ID: \(error)")
  } else if let result = result {
    print("Remote instance ID token: \(result.token)")
  }
}
```

I get this error with the second part:

> Static member 'instanceID' cannot be used on instance of type 'InstanceID'

Not sure what to do to fix it. Please help.
Note that I've conformed my AppDelegate class to MessagingDelegate.

Comment: Could you confirm the version of InstanceID that you are using. The latest version is 3.1.1. I would advise using that.